# Error on trying to retrieve an object stored in session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting the following error:

```
 NoMethodError in StoreController#add_to_cart
 undefined method `product_id' for #<Hash:0xb9d34aa0>

 Extracted source (around line #11):

 9      @cart_items = find_cart_items
 10      @cart_total_price = session[:cart_total_price]
 11     item = @cart_items.find {|i| i.product_id == product}
 12      if item
 13        item.update_quantity_by_one
 14      else
```

store_controller.rb

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController

  def index
      @products = Product.salable_items
  end

  def add_to_cart
      product = Product.find(params[:id])
        @cart_items = find_cart_items
      @cart_total_price = session[:cart_total_price]
        item = @cart_items.find {|i| i.product_id == product}
      if item
        item.update_quantity_by_one
      else
        li = LineItem.new
        if li.save
          li.for_product(product)
          @cart_items << li
        else
          flash[:alert] = "Error encountered."
        end
      end

      #@cart_items << LineItem.for_product(product)
      @cart_total_price += product.price
        redirect_to display_cart_path
  end

  def display_cart
      @items = session[:cart_items]
  end

  private 
    def find_cart_items
        if session[:cart_items].nil?
        session[:cart_total_price] = 0
        session[:cart_items] = Array.new
      else
        session[:cart_items]
      end
    end
end
```

line_item.rb

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product

    def for_product(product) 
        update_attribute(:quantity, 1)
        update_attribute(:product, product)
        update_attribute(:unit_price, product.price)
    end

    def update_quantity_by_one
        self.quantity += 1
    end
end
```

I get this error on adding the **second item** to the cart i.e. when there is one `LineItem` already present in `session[:cart_items]`. I have simulated this sequence of events in the rails console where everything works fine and I am able to retrieve the correct object on executing `@cart_items.find {|i| i.product_id == product}`, but when I launch in the browser, the above said error occurs. What might the problem be? Why is a 'hash' getting retrieved?

Comment: What you are trying to do? As per your code `@cart_items` doesn't contain `product_id`.

Comment: @cart_items is an array of LineItems which contains a field product_id. I am trying to add items to the cart, while detecting if the item being added is already present in the cart. Each item is identified by product_id

Comment: You have `@cart_items = find_cart_items` What is value of `session[:cart_items]` in `find_cart_items` method?

Comment: Find_cart_items is a private method in store_controller I've put up above.

Comment: I can see that. What's the value of `session[:cart_items]`?

Comment: session[:cart_items] is not an array as you expect, it's a hash.  Check how it was initially assigned

Comment: I expected session[:cart_items] to be an array of LineItems. Any suggestions for how I could store an array of LineItems in a session? @Pavan initially I suppose it's an empty array, then the first LineItem is added to it. Is there any way I can access session[:xyz] on rails console?

Comment: Please edit the title of the question to be more description. There are _many_ questions where the title includes "undefined error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`item = @cart_items.find {|i| i.product_id == product}`

Seems `i` is a Hash, so you can't call `#product_id` on it.

Try `i['product_id']` or `i[:product_id]`. If that doesn't work, try to debug using [pry](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails) or some similar tool, and figure out what `i` is.

---

Also, this doesn't seem to make sense:

`item = @cart_items.find {|i| i.product_id == product}`

Don't you mean:

`item = @cart_items.find {|i| i.product_id == product.id}`

Comment: Yes that's what I mean

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are attempting to save an array of ActiveRecord objects in the session.

Session data is serialized, and sometimes with unexpected results.  There are many references to how this can be a problem, for example,
[Railscasts: Dangers of Model in Session](http://railscasts.com/episodes/13-dangers-of-model-in-session?view=comments).

To see what's going on, you can stop & debug (or just puts) the @cart_items variable, right after line 9 in your controller.  I'll bet the @cart_items variable does not contain what you think. (It seems like the session is deserializing it as an array of Hashes.)

The standard advice is to save an array of LineItem id's in the session rather than an array of LineItem objects themselves.  Then the session serialization/deserialization should work very simply with no surprises.